# Azure API Management Policy for validate Request Parameter Values

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-api-management, policies, ibm-api-management

I need to validate parameter values in every request received. The validation will match every suscriptión ID to his posible parameter values.
I can't do it in the backend service, seems that the standard "validate-parameters" policy don't allow this, and don't want to use any other azure resource that involves a cost (f.e. other webservice).
I'm thinking in write a policy that validates reading a APIM Named Value than contains a JSON with the structure that relates suscriptions IDs with his posible parameter values.

Is this a correct aproach? Any other idea or suggestion to make this with less effort and/or more simplicity?